# Pseudoautosomal regions of the X chromosome showing heterozgyosity

Tags: reproduction, human-genetics, gene-expression

I've always had questions for myself about sex differentiation, mostly on account of an unusual history & puberty. I won't go into details, but needless to say it was unique.

My question is... I got results back from 23andme showing hetereozygosity at the beginning & ending of the X

I've been diagnosed as XY androgen insensitive & pseudohermaphrodite with mullerian structures intact.  Born with questionable stuff internally, only definitive thing is nothing male (no prostate, no seminal etc..)

They also did show a Y, but it was apparently missing half of it (though I've read thats not unusual for half of it to be --)

Can you have a hetereozygosity at the ends of the x and not have another x?

rs6644972   X   178624  AG
rs28475515  X   182276  CT
rs28463388  X   191998  TT
rs28669107  X   195014  CC
i6033542    X   200928  CC
rs6655397   X   201935  GG
rs7890186   X   202458  GG
i6033543    X   209741  CC
i6033544    X   215805  CC
rs28736870  X   220770  GG
i6033545    X   228250  GG
rs6603204   X   298440  GG
i6033547    X   301596  CC
rs2738344   X   310897  AA

Answer (score 1):

A normal male can show heterozygosity in the "X" results of a 23andMe [SNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism) test despite having only one X chromosome.  This is because there are very short regions at the ends of the Y chromosome, called [pseudoautosomal regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoautosomal_region), that match up with equivalent ([homologous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_homology)) regions at the ends of the X chromosome.

Because the pseudoautosomal regions of the Y are homologous to the matching regions of the X, the SNP results for those areas cannot be distinguished in the SNP tests, so the results appear along with the X results in "X" chromosome file.  The results in those two areas of the file can be either homozygous or heterozygous at each location.  Most of the locations in the "X" file are for  locations outside of those regions, so most of the file entries cannot report heterozygous results.